# Select com operador LIKE usando um array

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, db2

Estou tentando fazer um select com operador LIKE usando um array, porém está me retorando erro ao formar a string.

**SCRIPT**

```
placeholder= '?'
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in NAMES)
query= "select * from DADOS where CLIENTNAME like %%s%" % placeholders 
ibm_db_cur.execute(query, NAMES)
resultFinal = ibm_db_cur.fetchall()

for linha in resultFinal:
        print(linha)
```

**OUTPUT**

> ValueError: incomplete format

**API BD**

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
```

**ARRAY**

```
NAMES = ['client1','client2','client3']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo, o problema é que você colocou o identificador `%s` entre `%`, assim o python se perde na hora de substituir.
Altere seu código para:

```
query= "select * from DADOS where CLIENTNAME like %%s%".format(placeholders)
```

Obs: repare que a saída do select que você esta montando vai ser:

```
select * from DADOS where CLIENTNAME like %?, ?, ?%
```

Comment: Opa, era isso mesmo amigo, muito obrigado!